# Rails Post request loading indicator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, http-post

My rails app is sending long running post requests. I want some way of indicating to my users that their request is being run and that they shouldn't click away. What's the easiest way to do this?

Like a full screen, gray, loading screen.

Comment: 1. Put this task to the background job, so the response you can send fast to user. Or, 2. Use some CSS + Jquery to spinning and make the page disable, until you received the response back from the server...

Answer (score 0):

u can use jquery block UI http://malsup.com/jquery/block/ which will block screen while making ajax request .